# Reshaped HDD, Shared disk part. with Windows, then grub got corrupted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I have SSD(W10 only), and 1tb HDD (Ubuntu Only).
I decided to leave 300gb for the Ubuntu, I wanted to share the rest(600gb) between W10 and Ubuntu.

1. Reshaped HDD, left 300gb for ubuntu
2. Splitted 600gb into two, one of them NFTS, other is FAT32; because I don't know which one would work best for dual shared usage.
3. I can reach W10 via GRUB but Ubuntu page doesn't load. Even Ubuntu Recovery Mode doesn't work.

My questions are:

1. Did the first attempt has corrupted the Ubuntu or the second?
2. Is is it healthy to share the HDD in such a way?
3. If 2 is 'yes', then which file format should I use? NFTS or FAT32?

I read that FAT32 is absolutely compatible with all operating systems. But because of it is old, it may cause problems with large files etc. And NFTS is mostly for Windows, even though Ubuntu can read NFTS format.

Edit: I booted into live usb Ubuntu, tried Boot-Repair (Recommended), and didn't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After booting into Ubuntu Recovery Mode, an error raised which said basicly sda2 was corrupted.
So, I ran `fsck /dev/sda2`
And Ubuntu booted without problem.
It appears that when I re-formatted the HDD, Ubuntu files got corrupted.